# Interacting with a canvas object

Tags: html, vb.net, canvas

**This question is related to Visual Basic .NET 2010**

Is it possible to interact with a canvas object on a webpage using VB.NET? It's a drawing surface and I want to know if it's possible to interact with it programmatically, and if so, how?

Here's the canvas I want to interact with:

```
<canvas class="pulpBG" width="819" height="614" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 614.25px; width: 819px; opacity: 1;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, all html5 canvas drawing commands are issued in javascript code only.**

The workaround would be to create the data in VB.net that is used by javascript to issue drawing commands like lineTo, rect, arc, etc.

If you use a framework such as MVVM or MVC, you can create a viewmodel or model in VB.

Then on the browser you can use that viewmodel/model to drive canvas drawing commands in javascript.